# Browser slow on rendering a grid of 5600 divs with img inside

Tags: javascript, html, image, grid, rendering

Let's say I have a javascript that, after some calculation, write a string like

```
str += '<div class="divClass"><img class="imgClass" src="all_images/'+ result_image +'.png" /></div>';
```

The string is needed to populate a "grid" of images, and I need to update the string at least 15 times per second.

Problem is, as you may guess, the browser is really slow on doing this job...

any idea on how to improve the "rendering" time?

Any input appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using 5600 divs? What is your base html?

Comment: Is this snippet inside a loop that will run 5600 time and will result in massive string with that many image containing divs?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm basically "reading" a video, extracting the RGB value for every pixel, and build a grid of images to emulate the original video. The grid is 100x56, so I need 5600 little images to build a single frame of the video.. (please note: this won't go online, but everything runs locally.. so there aren't problem related to retrieving the images from the server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this loading 5600 individual images? If so, if the images are pretty small you could try combining them into a [sprite](http://alistapart.com/article/sprites) and then calling the single image, and specifying a background position to display the individual images at the given locations. Reducing 5000+ image calls would help significantly.

Comment: This is smart, thanks. I'll try your solution tomorrow.. Anyway, everything has to work locally, so I'm wondering if 5600 image calls are really "time consuming"? I mean, the browser helper has just to take the image from a folder and place it inside a div!

Comment: Every time it makes a call to find the image it has to interpret the path you are giving it, go and look for the image, verify it has found the image, take the image back to the browser, then render it, then cache it. If you have a single image it only needs to do that once, then the image is essentially available straight away in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

@Lucio Part of the delay is that the browser needs to rebuild the DOM with each newly created div. Try building the grid in HTML first then all you need to do is fill in the image file info i.e.

```
imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".divClass img");
for(x=0; x<imgs.length; x++ ) {
   imgs[x].src = "all_images/'+ result_image[x] +'.png";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I was already thinking to use your solution since my grid has not to be responsive in any way, but is really a 100x56 grid.. So first I'll try to build the HTML grid with 56 fixed-width columns and 1000 fixed-height rows.. But maybe i'll also use Rob's solution and use a sprite to place the div's background image.. Thanks guys, I'll keep you informed on the result